# Firefox SDK information from different contentscripts and main

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, message-passing

Hopefully my question was not answered yet, since there are a lot of related Q&As.
First, this is my add-on structure:

```
addon/  
 data/  
  contentScript1.js  
 lib/  
  lib1.js  
 main.js
```

Since the arrows are not working in markdown, I will describe it with words: add-on is the root, then two folders: `data` and `lib` and one file: `main.js`. Within `data` lies `contentScript1.js` and within `lib` lies `lib1.js`.

First I want to get a message from `contentScript1.js`, via `port.on` and `port.emit`:

```
//Part in main.js:  
var emitTest = "test";

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("contentScript1.js")],
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.port.on("clicked", function (data) {
            if(data == "clickBox1"){
                console.log(data); //this works
                pageMod.PageMod({
                    include: "*",
                    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("lib1.js")],
                    onAttach: function(worker2) {
                        worker2.port.emit("script2Test", "test");
                        worker2.port.emit("varTest", emitTest);
                        worker2.port.on("gotBack", function (data2) {
                            console.log(data2); //doesnt log
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});

//Part in lib1.js:
self.port.on("script2Test", function(data) {
    self.port.on("varTest", function(data2) {
        self.port.emit("gotBack", functionInLib1(data, data2));
    });
});
```

I skipped the part of `contentScript1.js`, since the message passing between these two (`contentScript1` and `main`) is working properly.

My question now is: Why is the marked `console.log` not working? I really tried to pass the messages right with `port.on` and `port.emit`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you put lib1.js inside the lib folder instead of the data folder. Since you're using

```
contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("lib1.js")],
```

you should put the lib1.js in the data folder.

Comment: First: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunatelly, this didn't solve my problem. Furthermore I added a console.log(data) in the lib1.js, that is not called either (straight after self.port.on("script2Test", function(data) {).

Comment: Did you try adding a log after onAttach: function(worker2) { to see if that part works?

Comment: Yep, I am always adding such "troubleshooting" outputs. But I omitted these in the stackoverflow question...and the console log is not called (no output)

Comment: I think you'll find that if you refresh the page, that console.log should be called. After you apply pageMod, the content script only loads on the next page refresh. Also, every time 'clicked' gets emitted it'll apply the pageMod, making whatever lib1.js does run twice. I'm not sure if this is what you want? If you want to apply the contentScript on the fly to the current page, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#Attaching_Content_Scripts_to_Tabs specifically require("sdk/tabs").activeTab.attach